# Java SWT: Table scroll doesn't work in Dialog

Tags: java, swt, windowbuilder

I need to add a table to a dialog, and I'm populating it with fake content. When the dialog is displayed, the table doesn't have scroll, so the content on the end is not visible.

Maybe it's related with the point that the Dialog is not resizable? I can't find the way to make the dialog resizable. It is possible?

This is the way I'm openning the Dialog:

```
BetClubDialog dialog = new BetClubDialog(getShell(), SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL, null);
String result = dialog.open();
```

This is my Dialog with a Table and with dummy content:

```
public class BetClubDialog extends Dialog {

    protected String result;
    protected Shell shell;
    private Club clubToEdit;

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     * @param parent
     * @param style
     */
    public BetClubDialog(Shell parent, int style, Club clubToEdit) {
        super(parent, style);
        this.clubToEdit = clubToEdit;
        setText("Gestionar Peña de Apuesta");
    }

    /**
     * Open the dialog.
     * @return the result
     */
    public String open() {
        createContents();

        Rectangle parentSize = getParent().getBounds();
        Rectangle shellSize = shell.getBounds();
        int x = parentSize.x + (parentSize.width - shellSize.width) / 2;
        int y = (int) (parentSize.y + (parentSize.height - shellSize.height) / 3.5);
        shell.setLocation(new Point(x, y));
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Composite topComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        topComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        topComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));

        Label lblClubName = new Label(topComposite, SWT.NONE);
        lblClubName.setText("Peña:");

        Label lblClubNameValue = new Label(topComposite, SWT.NONE);
        lblClubNameValue.setText("Dummy");

        Composite clubComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        clubComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        clubComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

        Table membersTable = new Table(clubComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        membersTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
        GridData gd_membersTable = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1);
        gd_membersTable.minimumHeight = -1;
        membersTable.setLayoutData(gd_membersTable);

        TableColumn tblclmnName = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
        tblclmnName.setWidth(150);
        tblclmnName.setText("Nombre");

        TableColumn tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
        tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber.setWidth(120);
        tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber.setText("Teléfono");

        TableColumn tblclmnCommonMoney = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
        tblclmnCommonMoney.setWidth(150);
        tblclmnCommonMoney.setText("Participación Habitual");   

        // populate Table
        for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(membersTable, SWT.NONE);                    
            tableItem.setText(new String[] {"person "+i, "610610620", "100"});
        }                       

        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the dialog.
     */
    private void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());
        shell.setSize(550, 550);
        shell.setText(getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I finally solved it removing this line:

```
 gd_membersTable.minimumHeight = -1;
```